# (PHPMailer) Connection to SMTP Server Failing (EHLO Command Failed) (Ubuntu 18.04.1)

Tags: php, smtp, apache2, phpmailer, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to send an email via a php script running in apache2 in Ubuntu 18.04.1 using PHPMailer but it is failing, after the connection is opened. I have debugging enabled and the output is as follows:

```
2019-02-20 11:18:17 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, 
timeout=300, options=array()  
2019-02-20 11:18:17 Connection: opened  
2019-02-20 11:23:17 SERVER -> CLIENT:  
2019-02-20 11:23:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost  
2019-02-20 11:23:17 SERVER -> CLIENT:        
2019-02-20 11:23:17 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:         
2019-02-20 11:23:17 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if 
connected   
2019-02-20 11:23:17 Connection: closed        
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP connect() failed.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting  
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.  
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I think that this is a networking issue as I even have difficulty pinging external servers such as "google.com", no packets are returned and I get 100% packet loss. However, I can "dig google.com" and get an ip address in return.

I can also do "telnet smtp.office.365 587" which again, returns an ip address as well as the domain "LHR-efz.ms-acdc.office.com".

It seems to me that I have an issue with traffic coming to my PC which could be why the SMTP connection is failing.

Comment: I have found O365 can be unreliable anyway, but this does look like network trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
2019-02-20 11:18:17 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, 
...
2019-02-20 11:23:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
```

Your SMTP client has connected to the Office365 server, then your client is claiming that **it** is the office365 mail server. While I would rarely credit Microsoft with words like consistency, reliability or predictability, I am not surprised their server doesn't want to talk to you after that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please could you explain where my client claims that "it is" the office365 server?

Comment: `CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost`